# expand/collapse div (toggle) when clicking on header

Tags: php, jquery, slidetoggle

I have the following jQuery code to toggle the view of more information in a div.

```
$(".expandCollapse").click(function () {
    var bidValue = this.id,
    expandArea = $("#"+bidValue+'_status')
    expandArea.slideToggle(500);
});
```

The code works to toggle the view of displaying more information when the submission header is clicked. The div IDs of $moreInfo are dynamically created.

```
$moreInfo = $bidValue.''."_status";

echo "<div class='expandCollapse' id='$bidValue'>Submission</div>";

echo "<div id='$moreInfo'>$displayComments</div>";
```

However I want to open only one view/div at a time.  If a div is open when a submission is clicked it should be closed before the other one is opened.

I've tried several things but it closes or hides all divs. Searching the web only show a solution using anchor tags.

Any thoughts...?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you can put a common class on the second `div` element to allow you to hide them all before showing the next, like this:

```
echo '<div id="$moreInfo" class="expand-area">$displayComments</div>';
```

```js
$(".expandCollapse").click(function () {
    var bidValue = this.id,
    expandArea = $("#" + bidValue + '_status').slideToggle(500)
    $('.expand-area').not(expandArea).hide();
});
```

Also note that you can make your code much more simple and generic by usnig DOM traversal to select the elements, instead of building selector strings based on related `id` attributes, like this:

```
$(".expandCollapse").click(function () {
    var expandArea = $(this).next('.expand-area').slideToggle(500);
    $('.expand-area').not(expandArea).hide();
});
```

The code above assumes that the elements are siblings, but you can easily amend the `next()` to traverse however is required.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the header and content divs are siblings you may use:

```
$(.expandCollapse + div)          
// All <div>s that are immediately after an .expandCollapse
```

```js
$(".expandCollapse").click(function () {
  var bidValue = this.id,
      expandArea = $("#"+bidValue+'_status')
  expandArea.slideToggle(500);
  $('.expandCollapse + div').not(expandArea).hide();
});
$('[id$="_status"]').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class='expandCollapse' id='bidValue1'>Submission1</div>
<div id='bidValue1_status'>displayComments</div>

<div class='expandCollapse' id='bidValue2'>Submission2</div>
<div id='bidValue2_status'>displayComments</div>


<div class='expandCollapse' id='bidValue3'>Submission3</div>
<div id='bidValue3_status'>displayComments</div>
```